# How can I set some defaultValues fields as a number but still set the field empty in react-hook-form?

Tags: react-hook-form

Here are the defaultValues in my form:

```
  const defaultValues = {
    category: '',
    itemName: '',
    author: '',
    brand: '',
    publisher: '',
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    isbn: '',
    danacode: '',
    barcode: '',
    condition: '',
    maxLoanPeriod: '',
    streetName: '',
    streetNumber: '',
    city: '',
    zipCode: '',
  }

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitSuccessful },
    watch,
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    mode: 'onChange',
  })
```

How can I set some of the defaultValues as a number but still leave the field empty? (and not specify 0 for example)

When I use the code snippet provided in the attached above, it prevents me from properly registering the correct types in the FormValues for the onSubmit function.

In order to avoid any type errors, I am required to specify the type as string for all the values, even if I intend some of them to be numbers:

```
type FormValues = {
   category: string
   itemName: string
   author: string
   brand?: string
   publisher?: string
   description: string
   imageUrl: string
   isbn?: string
   danacode?: string
   barcode?: string
   condition: string
   maxLoanPeriod: string
   streetName: string
   streetNumber: string
   city: string
   zipCode: string
}

   const onSubmit = async (data: FormValues) => {
     try {
       console.log(data)
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
     }
   }
```